# How to fix 'NOT NULL constraint failed' when I'm sending data for this field from django form

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I have a use-case for a django app where I need to save a form with some validation. Everything works fine until I hit the submit button. An integrity error is raised on the last_salary field.

But what's weird is the fact that I'm passing data for that field in the form and I even confirmed it by checking `request.POST` in the view.

I couldn't think of much to try since this behaviour is pretty weird. I did try to fill even the fields which aren't required to see if that worked but it didn't (obviously?). It should be noted that I'm using sqlite db.

My model is as follows:

```py
class EmployeeTestModel(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    last_salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    uk_resident = models.BooleanField()
    resume_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='media/',
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf'])]
    )
```

My view is:

```py
class EmployeeFormView(FormView):
    form_class = EmployeeTestForm
    template_name = 'form_app/form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('submission_success')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

With all the required fields filled, I expect it to save the form successfully but it raises the error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: form_app_employeetestmodel.last_salary

How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you need `last_salary` must not be null or it's optional? And do you inout last salary in the form?

Comment: `last_salary` is required and I did fill it in the form as I mentioned in the question. I even double-checked it in the view by checking if `request.POST` had a value against this field.

Comment: change this and run migrations ` last_salary = models.PositiveIntegerField(default-0)` just for test and let me know

Comment: Also can you add `EmployTestForm` in your question?

Comment: with default set for last_salary, it raised the same error for uk_resident. But when I set a default for that too, it worked. How though?

Comment: I didn't think defaults were mandatory.

Comment: Just print what you get in request.POST

Comment: I got a QueryDict with these form values `{'full_name': ['drake'], 'post_code': [''], 'last_salary': ['1']}`

Comment: No value for uk_resident and for this value which null constraint error occured?

Comment: uk_resident is a checkbox and there's no value for it because I didn't send any. The error was same as for last_salary. I must point out, however, that with defaults set for both last_salary and uk_resident, the form submits successfully